# Сделать картинку фоном в HTML письме

Tags: html, css

Вот макет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код

```
<table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" style="max-width: 464px; min-width: 290px;">
    <tr>
       <td align="center">
           <table align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="80%" border="0" style="background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFEA87 0%, #FFFAE5 100%);border-radius: 5px;border-spacing:0;border-collapse:separate; overflow: hidden; text-align: center; max-width: 288px; min-width: 136px;">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="center" height="20" valign="middle" width="100%"><a href="#" target="_blank" style="text-decoration: none; color: #000000; background: linear-gradient(180deg, #FFEA87 0%, #FFFAE5 100%);display: block;font-family: 'Play', Tahoma, sans-serif; font-size: 11px; font-weight: 400; width: 100%; line-height: 12px; ">Переход на сайт</a></td>
                    </tr>
              </table>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

То есть получается вот так

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно вставить картинку крана за кнопкой "переход на сайт" ?

Comment: Может добавить еще одну родительскую таблицу с одной ячейкой (в которой будет уже таблица с кнопкой), и у этой ячейки указать стили фона?

Comment: Также старайтесь использовать доверенные хостинги для изображений или убедитесь в том, что ваш адрес является таковым, ибо многие почтовые клиенты блокируют показ картинок от непроверенных источников, ссылаясь на настройки приватности получателя.

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте задать backgoung-image тэгу. или сделать див на одном ряду с td и сделать ему z-index -1.  Еще можно сделать через position absolute